# Schedule airflow to run on weekdays

Tags: airflow

What's the correct way to schedule an Airflow Dag so that it only runs on weekdays? I've tried including the hour offset both in the start_date and in the schedule_interval expression, but it's still not starting at the desired time. (I want it to start on January 28th at 1am UTC, and run at that time Tuesday through Saturday.)

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 28, 0, 0),
    'email': ['me@myplace.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
}

dag = DAG(
    'tasks', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="0 01 * * 2-6")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. Apparently this is considered like a @daily interval, so I need to set start_date to the 27th.